# How to count words in a sentence of a text in multiple sentences in python

Tags: python, string, text, words, sentence

I've searched around for a solution to this problem but I haven't found it yet. I have a large text file which is divided into sentences, separated only by "." I need to count how many words each sentence has and write it into a file. I'm using a separate file for this part of the code and so far I have this

```
    tekst = open('father_goriot.txt','r').read()
    tekst = tekst.split('.')
```

With this I get a 'list' type variable with each sentence in it's own index. I know that if I write

```
    print len(tekst[0].split())
```

I get the number of words in the first sentence. What I need is some kind of a loop to get the number of words in each sentence. After that I would need this data to be written into a file in a form:
1. index number of the sentence in a text, 2. number of words in that particular sentence, 3. number of words in the same sentence in a different text (which is a translation of the first text by using code in a seperate file), 4. number of the words that both sentences have in common.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After searching around for a while and for a simpler solution I've stumbled upon a code which gives me a partial result of what I want. The number of words in each sentence. It's represented by a list of numbers and it looks like this:

```
    wordcounts = []
    with open('father_goriot.txt') as f:
       text = f.read()
       sentences = text.split('.')
       for sentence in sentences:
           words = sentence.split(' ')
           wordcounts.append(len(words))
```

But the number is incorrect because it also counts something more. So for the first sentence I get a result of 40 instead of 38 words. How can I fix this.

Answer (score -1):

Just enumerate the whole file:

```
import re

with open('data.txt') as data:
    for line, words in enumerate(data):
        args = line + 1, re.split(r'[!?\.\s]+', words) # formatter
        print('Sentence at line {0} has {1} words.'.format(*args))
```

Comment: Thank you for a speedy answer but this bit counts the number of occurances of each word. This is not what I'm looking for...

Comment: I need the number of words in each sentence. The text file consists of 1548 sentences which have different number of words. So I'm looking for a loop to find how many words each of the 1548 sentence has and print it in the form of print("Sentence ", sentence_index, " has ", number_of_words, " words."

Comment: @BLaZZeD There you go.

Answer (score -1):

You need to loop through the file and read line by line something like this:

```
file = open('file.txt', 'r')

for line in file:
    do something with the line
```

Answer (score -1):

To get a list where each item corresponds to the a sentence:

```
def count_words_per_sentence(filename):
    """
    :type filename: str
    :rtype: list[int]
    """
    with open(filename) as f:
        sentences = f.read().split('.')
    return [len(sentence.split()) for sentence in sentences]
```

To test how many words two sentences have in common, you should use set operations. For example:

```
 words_1 = sentence_1.split()
 words_2 = sentence_2.split()
 in_common = set(words_1) & set(words_2)  # set intersection
```

For the file io, check out the csv module and the writer function. Construct your rows as a list of lists -- check out `zip` -- and then feed it to the csv writer.

```
word_counts_1 = count_words_per_sentence(filename_one)
word_counts_2 = count_words_per_sentence(filename_two)
in_common = count_words_in_common_per_sentence(filename_one, filename_two)
rows = zip(itertools.count(1), word_counts_1, word_counts_2, in_common)
header = [["index", "file_one", "file_two", "in_common"]]
table = header + rows

# https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
with open("my_output_file.csv", 'w') as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)
     writer.writerows(table)
```

Comment: In the brackets at def count_words_per_sentence() what do I write? If I write the name of the file I get an invalid syntax error....

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. You should be passing in the file name as a string to `count_words_per_sentence` -- i.e. `count_words_per_sentence("father_goriot.txt")`.